# How to do a foreach loop on each individual object in a custom object in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do a foreach loop on each instance of a line within a custom object but the foreach is taking the custom object as a whole.

I.e,

```
$ADUsersCustomObject = New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject
$ADUsersCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name email -Value $ADUsers.EmailAddress
$ADUsersCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name first_name -Value $ADUsers.givenName
$ADUsersCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name last_name -Value $ADUsers.Surname
$ADUsersCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name extension_number -Value $ADUsers.IPPhone

$ADToXYCompare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ADUsersCustomObject -DifferenceObject $APACXYUsers.members -Property email -PassThru

foreach ($UserADObject in $ADToXYCompare){

# Do X and Y

}
```

The problem is that $UserADObject is returning everything as a whole:

```
+--------------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| email                                      | first_name    | last_name          | extension_number   |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| {abc@test.com, def@test.com, ghi@test.com} | {im, a, test} | {bee, sting, wasp} | {4100, 4101, 4102} |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

instead of returning a single instance of the object:

```
+--------------+------------+-----------+------------------+
| email        | first_name | last_name | extension_number |
+--------------+------------+-----------+------------------+
| abc@test.com | im         | bee       | 4100             |
+--------------+------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Any ideas?

FIXED!
Thank you!! I got it with:

```
$Fixed = @()

$ADUsers | ForEach-Object{

    $ADUsersCustomObject = New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject
    $ADUsersCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name email -Value $_.EmailAddress
    $ADUsersCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name first_name -Value $_.GivenName
    $ADUsersCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name last_name -Value $_.Surname
    $ADUsersCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name extension_number -Value $_.IPPhone
    $Fixed += $ADUsersCustomObject
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble comes from the fact that when you write :

`Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name email -Value $ADUsers.EmailAddres`s

You put put a list of `EmailAddress` of all `$ADUsers` into `email`.

You have to loop on `$ADUsers` to create one `$ADUserCustomObject` for each use of `$ADUsers` and then add it to `$ADUsersCustomObject`.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed! I'll add the solution in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!! I got it with:

```
$Fixed = @()

$ADUsers | ForEach-Object{

    $ADUsersCustomObject = New-Object -TypeName pscustomobject
    $ADUsersCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name email -Value $_.EmailAddress
    $ADUsersCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name first_name -Value $_.GivenName
    $ADUsersCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name last_name -Value $_.Surname
    $ADUsersCustomObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name extension_number -Value $_.IPPhone
    $Fixed += $ADUsersCustomObject
}
```